# Generate unique and reversible id for 20 digits interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math

I want to generate a new unique 20 digits string from a string that represent a number

For example :

```
 var uid = key.pseudoHash("00000000000000000000"), // "45021-78054-45021-16875"
     uid = key.pseudoHash("00000000000000000001"), // "15751-40213-97315-65348"
     ..
     uid = key.pseudoHash("99999999999999999999"); // "01197-95791-58880-58368"
```

How can I have this pseudohash function that make no collision and which can be reversed?

Comment: What's wrong with the identity function?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Why don't you just use the string itself as the ID

Comment: For simple obfuscation purpose

Comment: You tried with `CryptoJS`?

Comment: You should also be aware that you can have reversibility only with knowledge of a secret key, if that would be useful to you. Check out trapdoor one-way hash functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of many ways is to use a simple [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher):

```
// guaranteed random!
var key = [1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 0, 2, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7, 8, 1, 7];

function test(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      str[i] = (Number(str[i]) + key[i]) % 10
  }
  return str.join("");
}

console.log(test("00000000000000000000")); // 13318357290282977817
console.log(test("00000000000000000001")); // 13318357290282977818
console.log(test("99999999999999999999")); // 02207246189171866706
```

For more randomness, you can add more [confusion and diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion) steps.

This can easily be reversed by anyone. For secure algorithms, look into cryptography.

Comment: Thanks for your your reply I'm looking at ciphers.Does this method garanty no colision? And do I have to use the same key to reverse the process?

Comment: @sklts Yes, there are no collisions. The method can be reversed by subtracting the key (i.e. change the `+` on line 6 to a `-`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement this because it uses the shonky 'modulus' operator of JS (I found a bug in this with a unit test in C#):

```
var key = [1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 0, 2, 8, 2, 9, 7, 7, 8, 1, 7];

function test(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      str[i] = (Number(str[i]) + key[i]) % 10
  }
  return str.join("");
}

function untest(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      str[i] = (Number(str[i]) - key[i]) % 10
  }
  return str.join("");
}

document.write(test("1000000001")); // 2331835720
document.write("<br></br>");
document.write(untest("2331835720")); // oh dear this doesn't round-trip: actually returns 100000000-9 and not 1000000001

document.write("<br></br>");
document.write( -9 % 10 );
document.write("<br></br>");
```

You can avoid this by replacing % 10 with a modulus function (as per the C# snippet below):

```
static private int Mod(int x, int m)
{            
    return (x % m + m) % m;
}
```